# Long Term Support for Azure

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

What guarantee does Microsoft give to providing long term support for Azure?  If Microsoft was to shutdown Azure how long would they keep the Azure cloud up and running?  Has anyone regretted using a SQL Azure feature as it harmed their ability to move off of SQL Azure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK. A few questions there. Some can really only be answered officially by Microsoft but I'll take a stab at providing at least some detail for you.

*1. What guarantee does Microsoft give to providing long term support for Azure?*

Microsoft commit to providing at least 12 months notice for any disruptive change. This is set out in their Online Services Support Lifecycle document. http://support.microsoft.com/gp/OSSLpolicy

*2. If Microsoft was to shutdown Azure how long would they keep the Azure cloud up and running?*

Per the above. I would consider that a disruptive change and expect them to provide a minimum of 12 months notice.

*3. Has anyone regretted using a SQL Azure feature as it harmed their ability to move off of SQL Azure?*

There are very few features that are only available in SQL Azure. IN terms of shipping features I can only think of Federations off the top of my head. It's a unique feature in that it's only somewhat interesting for on-premise deployments as you don't typically have elastic capacity on tap on premise and you can probably take other approaches such as a monolithic DB server + storage partitioning to solve your problems. In short I haven't had such regrets.